# In Laravel Eloquent what is the difference between limit vs take?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In the documentation it shows the following:

To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a given number of results in the query, you may use the skip and take methods:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Alternatively, you may use the limit and offset methods:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->offset(10)
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

What are the differences between these two? Are there any differences in execution speed?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With the Query Builder, `take()` is just an alias for `limit()`:

```
/**
 * Alias to set the "limit" value of the query.
 *
 * @param  int  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function take($value)
{
    return $this->limit($value);
}
```

**NB** This is not to be confused with `take()` on Collections.

Comment: Is skip also an alias for offset?

Comment: @rotaercz Yes, it is :)

Comment: It is not "only" alias! It all depends if you are working with collections or "eloquent collections", the latter is *alias* kind, but if you use collections its simply limit kind of function that you know from RDBMS for collection object. See source https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1346 I added this comment for people running around using google without knowledge of that EloquentCollection is different but very similar to the Collection.

Comment: @Kyslik The OP's question relates specifically to the Query Builder and doesn't even mention collections. There isn't a `limit()` or  an`offset()` method on either `Support\Collection` or `Eloquent\Collection`

Comment: @RossWilson I know, thats why I added the "I added this comment..."

Answer (score 19):

`limit` only works for eloquent ORM or query builder objects, whereas `take` works for both collections and the ORM or Query Builder objects.

```
Model::get()->take(20);   // Correct
Model::get()->limit(20);  // Incorrect

Model::take(20)->get()    // Correct
Model::limit(20)->get()   // Correct
```

Comment: one is an eloquent method and the other is collection method
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-take
- https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_limit

Answer (score 3):

if **take** is used before **get**, it is the same as **limit**. If used after **get**, the action is performed by **php** itself.
that is

```
Model::limit(10)->get() = Model::take(10)->get()
```

and **take** to **get**

```
Model::take(10)->get()
```

Launched through  **Eloquent/Builder**

```
 public function take($value)
 {
     return $this->limit($value);
 }
```

method to be starts.
Sql

```
select * from `table` where
  `table`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 20
```

---

If used after get

```
Model::get()->take(10);
```

Launched through **Collection**

```
 public function take ($limit)
 {
     if ($limit<0) {
         return $this->slice($limit, abs($limit));
     }

     return $this->slice(0, $limit);
 }
```

method worked. and all the data is retrieved via sql and then **$limit** *(10)* are allocated via **php**

Sql

```
select * from `table` where
  `table`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit works for eleqoent. Mostly used with offset

e.g

```
Model::offset(10)->limit(10)->get()
```

In the case above, it means get 10 elements(limit) starting from the 10th element onwards(offset).

Take is mostly used with collections but can also be used as an alias of limit for eloquent models

Answer (score -2):

So `skip` and `offset` also `take` and `limit` serve same purpose. Consider them as aliases.

Consider 1st scenario -

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

Here we read as skip first 10 records before starting to retrieve records and then take 5 records after the skipped ones.

The 2nd scenario -

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->offset(10)
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

This reads the same as well, offset/skip first 10 and then take/limit 5, since they are equivalent to their counterparts `skip` and `take`.

In terms of execution speed, there is no difference.

It's just based on personal preference and code style to fit your preferred naming conventions or the specific context of your code.
You can choose whichever you find more readable and maintainable for your specific use case.

**Use Case:**
I have encountered this, when I was working with a team with diverse backgrounds.They were using explicit methods like `offset` and `limit`. Some SQL developers were migrated to be Full Stack Developers.

Whereas on an another project which was experienced with Laravel and prefered its conventions were using `skip` and `take`

Answer (score -2):

In Laravel Eloquent, limit and take are synonyms and can be used interchangeably to limit the number of results returned by a query. There is no difference in their behavior.